# How to do a simple captive portal with django http redirects?

Tags: django, redirect, iptables

I have a device running django and serving up an wireless access point.  I would essentially like to create a captive portal of sorts where any url entered would go to my django web page.

To accomplish this so far I have created an iptables rule like so (for now):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp –dport 80 -j DNAT –to 192.168.50.1:8000
```

This works in a way, except that if I go to for example "google.com", I get google.com shown in the browser url, but my django web page displayed.

What I would like is for mydjangowebpage.com to be shown in the url instead.  There seems to be a host of captive portal solutions that require dns servers, multiple iptables rules, radius servers, etc.

To me it seems like a simple solution would be to do that one rule I specified above, followed by some httpredirect command in django.  I would like to know if my urls.py dispatcher is capable of checking the actual site url (i.e. the "google.com" part), and if it is NOT "mydjangowebpage.com" to do a httpredirect to "mydjangowebpage".  Does that make sense?

I guess the urlpatterns looks for matches,  It seems to accomplish this the pattern would need to look for NOT matches and look at the whole url, not just the stuff after the site name.

For example, something along the lines of:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(lambda x: not models.get_current_site(request) == 'mydjangowebpage.com', lambda x: HttpResponseRedirect("http://mydjangowebpage.com")),
    ....
```

Comment: Hey! Can you share the guide you used for building and installing the Django app in the radius server?

Answer (score 2):

Well I found a way to do it.  I'll still leave it open in case there are better ways...

You can make use of a middleware filter.  I found this one [here](https://gist.github.com/robballou/283860) to work (called hostname_middleware.py).  I have copied it here for convenience:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django import http

class EnforceHostnameMiddleware(object):
    """
    Enforce the hostname per the ENFORCE_HOSTNAME setting in the project's settings
    The ENFORCE_HOSTNAME can either be a single host or a list of acceptable hosts
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            if not settings.ENFORCE_HOSTNAME:
                return None
        except AttributeError, e:
            return None

        host = request.get_host()

        # find the allowed host name(s)
        allowed_hosts = settings.ENFORCE_HOSTNAME
        if not isinstance(allowed_hosts, list):
            allowed_hosts = [allowed_hosts]
        if host in allowed_hosts:
            return None

        # redirect to the proper host name
        new_url = [allowed_hosts[0], request.path]
        new_url = "%s://%s%s" % (
            request.is_secure() and 'https' or 'http',
            new_url[0], urlquote(new_url[1]))
        if request.GET:
            new_url += '?' + request.META['QUERY_STRING']

        return http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(new_url)
```

Then add in your settings.py file (customize to fit your needs):

```
ENFORCE_HOSTNAME=['192.168.50.1','mydjangowebpage.com']
```

And add the middleware to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
'mydjangowebpage.hostname_middleware.EnforceHostnameMiddleware'
```

Now when I go to a url "facebook.com" or anything else, it will redirect the name to the first in the list.  Yay! Easy captive portal!